# Lost my contacts & calendar reminders after win 10 mobile update

Tags: windows-10-mobile, contacts, calendars, people

Am using Lumia 640XL. I updated from 8.1 to Win 10 last night. After update, I lost following:

1. Contacts: it shows only 4-5 contacts. Rest of them are gone. However I see on all Contacts on people.live.com
2. Calendar reminders: lost all reminders set for myself. I had plenty of them.
3. Messages & Call history: lost all messages & call history.

Calendar & Contacts are still exists on windows live a/c.

I would appreciate if anyone could answer and help me retrieving all messages, contacts & calendar reminders ASAP.

Just to validate, I downloaded third party calendar app (One Calendar). Added my account and surprisingly, I could see all my calendar reminders in app but I can't see same with Outlook Calendar app. Why??? Will expert here help me to resolve this issue?

Another, my account is not shown in Outlook Calendar & People people. (The way I see on Win 10 laptop).. no matter how many times, I add, it won't show. I see successful message. However, I see my a/c info on All Setting->Account

I had a chat with Microsoft Tech support, they recommended me to hard-reset phone however they don't guarantee that this will fix issue. :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All of your contacts and calendar reminders seem to be available online, right? Then I would agree with the MS Tech support to go ahead and do a hard reset. This usually does solve a lot of issues related to the W10 update.

Comment: Even tech support mentioned that they don't guarantee that doing hard reset will fix issue. hence I'm caution on doing this

Comment: I waited a lot for solution but didn't help. Finally, I took pain of "hard reset". I got my contacts & calendar reminder back however, it took tremendous amount of my time to update all apps, settings & install required apps; still not done. Phew!! Wish there was some way to reduce this effort..

Comment: Yea, but hopefully this will bea one time effort.

Comment: I tried this with no luck - the Outlook account never shows as being active, no matter how often I add it (and despite positive acknowledgement that it was successfull!). Contacts are still online and reachable on my laptop - a hard reset made no change. All contacts were there before the update to Win 10.